# How to speed up data download from Alpha Advantage API?

Tags: python, stock

Forgive my ignorance but I'm struggling with how to approach this. I'm trying to write a program which pulls back historical gappers and runs backtesting strategies on the data.

First I'm getting a list of tickers from [IEX cloud](https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/):

```
import requests #The requests library for HTTP requests in Python
import csv
import pandas as pd
from secrets import IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN_TEST
from secrets import IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN_LIVE

api_url = f'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/ref-data/iex/symbols?format=csv&token={IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN_LIVE}'
tickers = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(api_url)

    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')

    cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
    my_list = list(cr)
    for row in my_list[1:]:
        tickers.append(row[0])

print(tickers)
```

Then I'm looping over the tickers and using the [Alpha Vantage API](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) to pull 2 years worth of full market data:

```
stocksIntraDay = []
dates = ['year1month1', 'year1month2', 'year1month3', 'year1month4', 'year1month5', 'year1month6', 'year1month7', 'year1month8', 'year1month9', 'year1month10', 'year1month11', 'year1month12',
'year2month1', 'year2month2', 'year2month3', 'year2month4', 'year2month5', 'year2month6', 'year2month7', 'year2month8', 'year2month9', 'year2month10', 'year2month11', 'year2month12']

def getIntraday():
    # cycle through our symbols (only the first one for testing)
    for i in tickers[1]:
        ticker = i
        print(ticker)
        apiKey = 'MY_KEY'

        # alpha splits out the dates it gives us into 24 segments
        # cycle through the segments
        for i in dates:
            date = i

            # api string where we pass in the symbol and the current date
            api_url = f'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED&symbol={ticker}&outputsize=full&interval=1min&slice={date}&apikey={apiKey}'

            # download the csv file for each date
            with requests.Session() as s:
                download = s.get(api_url)
                decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')
                cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
                my_list = list(cr)
                for row in my_list:
                    print(row)


getIntraday()
```

The download is really slow. I've seen [this article here](https://medium.com/alpha-vantage/data-is-taking-to-long-to-get-back-d48e3bf8f59b) but I can't make sense of it. How can I speed up the download of the files and improve this code?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a gentle reminder, this is *not a discussion forum*; we are not interested in conversational/personal language, and we cannot help you design an overall project. Questions about the best, or "right" way to do something are considered off topic here as they are subjective and since the answer that best suits you is likely to be specific to you and the unique requirements of your project. Stack Overflow is here to help solve problems, not to find the right problem to solve.

Comment: Ok thanks Karl I'll update my question

Comment: Karl is that better?

Comment: Karl if stackoverflow isn't the place to ask for projection direction do you know of a website I can?

Comment: How slow is it?  You're making 24 separate web requests for each stock symbol.  It's never going to be speedy, especially if your network is suboptimal.

Comment: Additionally, the API might not *want* you to be able to make many requests quickly. They have to serve many other customers, after all. From their own documentation: "Are there usage/frequency limits for the API service?

We are pleased to provide free stock API service for our global community of users for up to 5 API requests per minute and 500 requests per day. If you would like to target a larger API call volume, please visit premium membership."

Comment: The article you found is talking about how to make web requests in parallel, in a general  sense. If you don't understand that explanation, you should use a search engine to find other explanations of that general technique. You might try something like "python threading tutorial". But that will only help you if you have a premium membership and won't get rate-limited by the server. That essentially makes the question off topic for Stack Overflow; we do not do tech support for AlphaVantage, or anyone else.